# Finding used functions from php source file

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

Basically I want to find a function from a php string source content. I'm trying to parse a php file and read its content into string. I want to find something like:

**`function_name(paras)` or `function_name()` or `function_name(params, params)`**

for example if source contains:

```
echo 'Greetings'.greet("I'm Johan");
$age = date_of_birth(date());
echo 'I am ' .$age . 'years old';
```

it would then find  **`greet`, `date_of_birth`, `date`**  because these are the functions used.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the parameters including nested brackets, like your `date_of_birth(date())`, its maybe not impossible with regex but very difficult.

If you say its enough to find the name of the function then you can try this:

```
\w+(?=\()
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u94h)

That will match at least one word character that is followed by an opening bracket.

`\w` contains letters, digits and the underscore

`(?=\()` is a positive look ahead that checks if a `(` is following

Answer (score 0):

you need a regular expression:
maybe something like this

```
preg_match("[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*(.*)",$stringToLookIn);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/([a-zA-Z_]\w+)\s*\(/', $source, $match);
var_dump($match[1]);
```